# Removing 'disabled' from CSS with jQuery

Tags: javascript, css

I'm using `.val()` to enter some data into a text box. However, when I go to click "add" I see that there is a disabled tag.

```
<input class="btn-primary action-submit" type="submit" value="Add" disabled="">
```

When I manually type in text, it disappears.

```
<input class="btn-primary action-submit" type="submit" value="Add">
```

Is there a way to remove it?

Comment: `Is there a way to remove it?` remove what?

Comment: "disabled" without having to type into the text box. When I add text in using `.val()` it still is there.

Comment: at what event do you want to remove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what exactly you want, but to remove attribute you could use **[Element.removeAttribute()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/removeAttribute)** method:

```
document.querySelector('.action-submit').removeAttribute('disabled');
//or
document.getElementsByClassName("action-submit")[0].removeAttribute('disabled');
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: yes! that worked. I was trying to do it in jquery and it wasn't working.

Comment: I can't see Jquery tag in your question but you could try `$('.action-submit').prop("disabled", false);`.

Comment: yea, this didn't work for me :-(

Comment: Should work, you can make a **[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jnwrc5ay/)**?

Answer (score 0):

To remove the `disabled` property with jQuery you would use this:

`$('.action-submit').removeProp('disabled');`